# Is ConcurrentBag(T) optimized for single-threaded scenarios? If so, why concurrent?

Tags: .net, multithreading, collections, concurrency

The MSDN documentation on the [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) class from .NET 4.0's concurrent collections library says this:

> ConcurrentBag is a thread-safe bag
>   implementation, **optimized for
>   scenarios where the same thread will
>   be both producing and consuming data
>   stored in the bag**. [emphasis mine]

Am I missing something, or is this saying that the `ConcurrentBag<T>` class is optimized for *single-threaded* scenarios?

If I'm *not* missing something... why would this be? It just seems pretty strange to have a collection *designed* for concurrency but *optimized* for one thread.

Comment: if the alternative is a collection that **isn't** designed for concurrency...

Comment: If they would have named it ConcurrentCache<>, would it make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimization means that, if you have multiple threads both producing and consuming, there are optimizations in place such that it's fastest if it can return an item that was placed in the bag by the same thread.

Where this optimization doesn't apply is if a thread asks the bag for an item, and there are no more items left in the bag that were placed there by that thread. In that case, it can still retrieve an item from the bag (placed in there by another thread), but it's less optimal.

---

Or, to put it another way: It's Concurrent because multiple threads can be producing into it and consuming from it simultaneously, without external locking. The mentioned optimization doesn't make this untrue.

Comment: Ah, OK... so it's more like, for any given thread accessing the bag, it's better for that thread to be both producing and consuming—as opposed to, only *one* thread should be producing/consuming. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

**What the documentation tries to say is that it prefers the same thread producing and consuming data.**

It has a fast path where when the same thread produces and consumes data, the data stays on that thread (think `[ThreadStatic]`). However, when there is no data to consume on the same thread, it goes looking on other threads and gets data from there.

Look e.g. at http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/01/27/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentBag.aspx for a more detailed explanation of this.

Comment: But other than producing and consuming... what is left? Isn't that essentially saying it prefers single-threaded access?

Comment: How does a collection "goes looking for data" ?

Comment: @Dan Tao - What that says is that an optimization is build in when the same thread produces and consumes. It of course still works (fast) when this is divided over different threads.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - I do not know how this is implemented. But the idea is that there are separate queues per thread which the bag looks in first without having to lock. When that queue is empty, it looks in queues of other threads, but then it has to lock them. There are articles on the internet which explain this mechanism, for example http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/01/27/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentBag.aspx, but there are others.

Answer (score 1):

Three scenarios where you might use a `ConcurrentBag` and how this optimization affects them:

1) Separate producer and consumer threads.  No effect.

2) Threads that are both consumers and producers storing and retrieving data from the `ConcurrentBag`.  The optimization will improve performance for same-thread add / retrieve operations.

3) Single threaded scenarios that could use a regular collection.  The optimization means that there is little overhead in using a `ConcurrentBag` so you can use it without a huge performance hit.